# C# OpenXml Excel Creation - can I set it to "Format as table"?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

When I am creating an Excel sheet using **DocumentFormat.OpenXml**  is there any way to specify that I want a range of cells (really the whole sheet) to be in the "Format as Table" (CTRL+T) representation?  Or is this not available in the OpenXML library?  I can't seem to find anything that says either way.  Thank you.

Comment: This is not the best answer, but Microsoft created a tool, where it'll dump the C# code associated with OpenXML based documents. This comes in handy with determining how Microsoft dictates how to display the documents they create.  
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Answer (score -3):

While I'm pretty sure you can do what you want purely with the OpenXML library, you also have the option of including the ClosedXML library which makes working with Excel a whole lot easier.

If I understand your question correctly, you are just looking for taking a data set of some kind and dump it as a table in a Excel-file, in which case, if you can boil your data down to a DataTable in C# the following should help you

```
//create some dummy table for this test
DataTable table = new DataTable();
//make a few columns
table.Columns.AddRange(
    new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("Column 1",typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Column 2", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Column 3", typeof(int)) }
);
//populate with some randomness
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var newRow = table.NewRow();
    newRow[0] = r.Next(0, 10);
    newRow[1] = r.Next(0, 10);
    newRow[2] = r.Next(0, 10);
    table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
//create workbook
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
var sheet = wb.AddWorksheet("My datatable");
//just showing how to add a bit of extra data to the sheet, not required
sheet.Cell(1, 1).SetValue<string>("Title: this is just a test");
sheet.Cell(1, 3).SetValue<string>("Date: " + DateTime.Now);
//dump table in sheet
sheet.Cell(2, 1).InsertTable(table);
sheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
wb.SaveAs(@"c:\test\dtable.xlsx",false);
```

This will result in the following Excel-document
[image: example of output from test program]

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is not an anwer using OpenXML.